# Сохранение Токена на время сеанса

Tags: javascript, html, jscript

сделал сайт, где используется токен для отправки сообщений/упревлений друзьями/смена статуса/и т.д. (просто для себя, попрактиковаться) Но я не знаю как сделать так, чтобы на главной страничке (она у меня готова, а вот js - нет) запрашивало токен, и как сделать так чтобы он сохранялся, даже при переходе на моем сайте на другую страничку, например: со вкладки друзья, перейти на вкладку сообщения, и сохранить введенный до этого токенг в поле ввода. Объясни как могу, заранее спасибо =)